# Does Convert.ToInt32(object) skip unboxing?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, unboxing

The IL produced from the following:

```
object[] items = new object[] { 341, "qwerty" };
int item1FromConvert = Convert.ToInt32(items[0]);
int item1FromCast = (int)items[0];
```

Is (according to LINQPad 4):

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0002:  newarr      System.Object
IL_0007:  stloc.3     // CS$0$0000
IL_0008:  ldloc.3     // CS$0$0000
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000A:  ldc.i4      55 01 00 00 
IL_000F:  box         System.Int32
IL_0014:  stelem.ref  
IL_0015:  ldloc.3     // CS$0$0000
IL_0016:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0017:  ldstr       "qwerty"
IL_001C:  stelem.ref  
IL_001D:  ldloc.3     // CS$0$0000
IL_001E:  stloc.0     // items
IL_001F:  ldloc.0     // items
IL_0020:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0021:  ldelem.ref  
IL_0022:  call        System.Convert.ToInt32
IL_0027:  stloc.1     // item1FromConvert
IL_0028:  ldloc.0     // items
IL_0029:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_002A:  ldelem.ref  
IL_002B:  unbox.any   System.Int32
IL_0030:  stloc.2     // item1FromCast
```

`item1FromConvert` appears to skip the unboxing stage typical when casting an `object` to an `int`, or any value type, (from my extremely limited understanding of IL - based on there is no unbox.any for the line above the line with the comment: // item1FromConvert).

Is this indeed the case and will Convert.ToValueType(object) always save me the unboxing if the object is the said value type?

Comment: Do you have the IL for System.Convert.ToInt32?  Does the unboxing happen in there?

Answer (score 3):

There's no boxing, but you are instead just getting a method call instead, which is just a different way of doing it.  It's not really going to save you time from a performance perspective.  All you're doing is calling `Convert.ToInt32(object)`, which the implementation of is:

```
 public static int ToInt32(object value) {
     return value == null? 0: ((IConvertible)value).ToInt32(null);
 }
```

(see here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs#3a271a647f117003)

So if anything, you're actually *decreasing* your performance because of the various operations happening in the implementation of `Convert.ToInt32(object)`, which you wouldn't have if you just cast the value in the first place.

You're trying to micro-optimise, and actually making the number of *total* IL instructions executed *increase*, because LINQPad won't show you the IL of the methods you're calling.

Comment: Thanks, but please don't assume I am trying to micro-optimise, the question is academic.

Comment: OK fair enough, you're right I shouldn't have assumed that, but I inferred it from your comment "save me the unboxing", where "save" suggests that you're trying to reduce something (e.g. overhead).